# pip install xlutils python3

Tags: python-3.x, xlutils

I'm trying to install xlutils package to access xls sheets in Python but unfortunately I'm unable to install it.

Python version 3.5.1

using spyder editor, have got this error.

```
runfile('E:/python_practice/task2/gen1.py', wdir='E:/python_practice/task2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "E:/python_practice/task2/gen1.py", line 10, in <module>
    from xlutils.copy import copy
ImportError: No module named 'xlutils'
```

so, downloaded xlutils from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils and unzipped, copied and pasted in sitepackages folder of python35 folder and as well as anaconda3 folder.But still i'm getting above mentioned error.

Comment: when am trying to install in cmd prompt it is saying requirement is already exists as i had copied the directory already. M new to python , so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the docs of this module? It clearly explains everythinf you should do. There is a way to install it using `pip`. Type this in your command-line: `pip install xlutils`. That should install it. For any further problems, read the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/installation.html).

EDIT: Never mind, this package is unavailable for Python 3.5

> This package is support on Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7 on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already gone through those steps but did not work. as  you said this package is unavailable for python 3.5 . then is there any other way/library to edit the existing excel sheet . My task is to add new rows (containing strings) in between rows of an existing excel sheet.please let me know how can i proceed. Thank you @Leva7

Comment: m glad if i can find a way to edit existing excel sheet by using python 3.5 itself

Comment: @venky Try `openpyxl` to edit a spreadsheet with Python 3.5. It must be in the `xlsx` format though, not the older `xls`.